# Issue with Updating Global/Local Variables

Tags: python, global-variables

Take a look at the example code below. There is a main window, which calls the function `fun2` to display the value of variable `a` (as a label w/ text). At the same time, a menu item on the main window launches a secondary window (function `fun1`) with two buttons. I am trying to find a way to change the value of `a` through these buttons.

If I do not include the global variable `a = 0` (line 6), I get a "global name 'a' is not defined" error. If I do include it (as in this example), the window buttons don't have any effect on the variable (it remains `a = 0`). I've tried using the command `global a` in `fun1`, with no effect. I've also experimented using the same command also in `fun2` but I still can't get it to work.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

```
import Tkinter
import random
import time
from Tkinter import *

a = 0

def fun1():
    win2 = Toplevel()
    win2.geometry("300x300")
    def var_yes():
        a = 1
        win2.after(500, lambda: win2.destroy())
    def var_no():
        a = 0
        win2.after(500, lambda: win2.destroy())
    button1 = Tkinter.Button(win2, text ="1", command = var_yes).pack()
    button2 = Tkinter.Button(win2, text ="2", command = var_no).pack()

def fun2():
    value = 0
    if a == 1:
        value = a
    granresult = "{}".format(value)
    lbl.configure(text = str(granresult))


def gui_stuff(window):
    global lbl
    window.configure(background="#000000")
    window.geometry("700x500")
    lbl = Tkinter.Label(window, height=5, anchor = "c", text="Label", bg="#000000", fg="#ffffff", font=("Helvetica", 22))
    lbl.pack()
    fun2()


window = Tkinter.Tk()
menubar = Menu(window)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Program", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="test", command=fun1)
window.config(menu=menubar)
gui_stuff(window)
window.update()
winx1 = window.winfo_rootx()
winy1 = window.winfo_rooty()
winh1 = window.winfo_height()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `global` statement must be used *in the function that assigns to the variable*. It does not carry over into sub-functions, which is why it didn't have an effect in `fun1`. You have to add it to both `var_yes` and `var_no`.

Comment: Clean, precise, easy-to-implement solution. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is thinking that global variables are a good idea.  Then not understanding how to use them.  In python you create a global by assignment in the module level scope.  You have done that by creating a value and calling it `a`

In each function which needs to write `a' you need to declare as global.  See the code

```
import Tkinter
import random
import time
from Tkinter import *

a = 0

def fun1():
    win2 = Toplevel()
    win2.geometry("300x300")
    def var_yes():
        global a
        a = 1
        win2.after(500, lambda: win2.destroy())
    def var_no()
        global a
        a = 0
        win2.after(500, lambda: win2.destroy())
    button1 = Tkinter.Button(win2, text ="1", command = var_yes).pack()
    button2 = Tkinter.Button(win2, text ="2", command = var_no).pack()

def fun2():
    global a
    value = 0
    if a == 1:
        value = a
    granresult = "{}".format(value)
    lbl.configure(text = str(granresult))


def gui_stuff(window):
    # the next line refers to a global which doesn't exist
    global lbl
    window.configure(background="#000000")
    window.geometry("700x500")
    lbl = Tkinter.Label(window, height=5, anchor = "c", text="Label", bg="#000000", fg="#ffffff", font=("Helvetica", 22))
    lbl.pack()
    fun2()


window = Tkinter.Tk()
menubar = Menu(window)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Program", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="test", command=fun1)
window.config(menu=menubar)
gui_stuff(window)
window.update()
winx1 = window.winfo_rootx()
winy1 = window.winfo_rooty()
winh1 = window.winfo_height()
window.mainloop()
```